# How to call identifier loop with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to do this loop but there's something wrong.
Do I need to loop variable c also?
Just to explain, There's a table and child(i) changes every row.

- SelectorT receives one sentence like: Now\nIs\n09:00\n4\n7
- VariableM splits the sentence in array:
- variableM[0] = Now
- variableM[1] = is
- variableM[2] = 09:00
- variableM[3] = 4
- variableM[4] = 7

So I need to return the first child(i), then run the next and return again.

```
const c = [1,2,3,4,5];

for (const property in c) {
    const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    
    const selectorT = '#Main > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child('+i+') > section:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1)';
    
    let variableM = document.querySelector(selectorT).innerText.split("\n")
    
    let variableH = variableM[0];
    
    let variableA[= variableM[1];
    
    let variableT = variableM[2];
    
    let variableS1 = parseInt(variableM[3]);
    
    let variableS2 = parseInt(variableM[4]);
    
    
    return {
      variableH , variableA, variableT, variableS1, variableS2
        }
                    
        })
        
    console.log(result);
    }
```

Comment: If you return inside the loop, the loop ends. What behavior did you expect?

Comment: I need to change child(i) everytime the loop runs. But even without return doesn't work because it's not writen correctly. And I need to show/return the output every row.

Comment: When I put outside the loop I got error to find the variable. (node:10404) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: variableH is not defined

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a loop perhaps you mean  `for (i = 1; i < 5; i++)`
there is a typo in this line `let variableA=variableM[1];`, also you are returning the values inside the loop they should be returned outside the loop

Comment: VariableM it's an Array where I store the whole string.

Comment: Maybe for each is better in my case?

Comment: can you add a snippet of the html , also do you want your variables in an array ?

Comment: I've update the code. Now It's looping but still need to loop child(i) like child(1), child(2), child(3), child(4), child(5).